# How do I convert a list of strings into a list of lists in Racket?

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I have a problem with converting a list of strings into a list of lists, as well as conversion of the items within each of the lists. Let's say I have the list:

`("ZZ 9 8" "T 188 8" "L 5 10")`

How could I convert this to become

`(("ZZ" 9 8) ("T" 188 8) ("L" 5 10))`

so that the numbers are numbers and the strings are strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `map` over each string, splitting it, leaving the first element as a string and converting the other elements to numbers. Something like this:

```
(define (convert strs)
  (map (lambda (str)
         (let ((strlist (string-split str)))
           (cons (first strlist)
                 (map string->number (rest strlist)))))
       strs))
```

For example:

```
(convert '("ZZ 9 8" "T 188 8" "L 5 10"))
=> '(("ZZ" 9 8) ("T" 188 8) ("L" 5 10))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is fragile to assume that only the first token in an input string should be left as a string and that all other strings should be converted to numbers. You can solve the problem easily by defining two procedures.

The `parse-nstring` procedure takes a string which may contain number tokens and returns a list of strings and numbers. The `string->number` procedure returns `#f` when it is unable to convert a string to a number. `parse-nstring` only uses the result of `string->number` when the conversion was successful; otherwise the original token is kept. This is accomplished by splitting the original space-delimited string into substrings, and mapping over that list with an anonymous procedure that takes a substring and returns a number if it can be converted to a number, or the original substring otherwise.

The `parse-nstrings` procedure takes a list of strings and returns a list containing the results of parsing each string. This procedure simply maps the `parse-nstring` procedure over the input list.

```
(define (parse-nstring str)
  (let ((substs (string-split str)))
    (map (lambda (subst) (let ((token (string->number subst)))
                           (or token subst)))
         substs)))

(define (parse-nstrings strs)
  (map parse-nstring strs))
```

```
strings-to-lists.rkt> (parse-nstrings '("ZZ 9 8" "T 188 8" "L 5 10"))
'(("ZZ" 9 8) ("T" 188 8) ("L" 5 10))

strings-to-lists.rkt> (parse-nstrings '("THX 11 38" "99 Red Ballons" "1 O'Clock 2 O'Clock 3 O'Clock Rock"))
'(("THX" 11 38) (99 "Red" "Ballons") (1 "O'Clock" 2 "O'Clock" 3 "O'Clock" "Rock"))
```